# Enable mouse wheel to change tabs in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to enable tab switching using the mouse wheel in Sublime Text 3.

I added this configurations to my User settings:

```
"enable_tab_scrolling": false,
"mouse_wheel_switches_tabs": true,
```

Also tried different order and values but none is working.

I always restart Sublime after changing my settings.

Anyone got this working?

Comment: `"mouse_wheel_switches_tabs": true,` only works if your theme supports it (try with the Default theme), and the mouse wheel will only switch tabs while the pointer is over the tab bar.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. By switching to the default theme I was able to use the mouse wheel to switch tabs. Maybe add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"mouse_wheel_switches_tabs": true,` only works if the following conditions have been met:

- the mouse pointer is over the tab bar while using the scroll wheel
- your theme supports it in conjunction with your preferences

  - try with the Default theme
  - tweak your theme to support it

The Default theme contains the following rule to enable this functionality:

```
{
    "class": "tabset_control",
    "settings": ["mouse_wheel_switches_tabs", "!enable_tab_scrolling"],
    "mouse_wheel_switch": true
},
```

Note that it doesn't work with `"enable_tab_scrolling": true,` so you did the right thing to set it to false.

You could add this rule to whichever theme you are using by creating a file with the same name as the `.sublime-theme` you are using, and pasting in the rule surrounded by square brackets - it needs to be a valid JSON array.

More information on how themes work can be found in the [official docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html).

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 the file should be placed at `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/`. To find out the name of your current active theme go to Preferences > Settings and search for `theme`.

Answer (score -1):

You haven’t registered Sunblime. It’s the Unregistered popup that is staying in the background messing with your scroll. Look for it and close it and the scroll will work again.

Comment: This happened to be the case for me. It was hidden under some other windows and I didn't even notice it popup. Thank you for saving me from a headache with such a simple answer.